# Iphone 5, 6, 6 plus ui design issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iphone-6

Is there any method to define frames for iphone 5 so that it can automatically adopted and adjusted by iphone 6 and 6 plus without using xib?

I don't want to define different frames for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus.

Comment: why don't you use 'inferred' option for frame size?

Comment: we have 3x image concept here. My confusion is should we go for 3x image size layout so that 1x and 2x would be adjusted according to that? because we have different screen sizes now. then how 3x images would be adjusted on all screen sizes?

Comment: images 3x will be used only on iphone 6 plus, for others @2x will be used, you should provide both

Answer (score 1):

You can use AutoLayout and Size classes to make one UI for alla devices.
[Size classes Design help](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/_index.html)

Comment: He is telling about without using XIB

Comment: You can use AutoLayout without using XIB, regardless why should you not use XIB when you have it. I can´t see any pros for programmatically developing all the UI.

Comment: I have my previous code which is not in xib. Now I want to switch it to xcode 6 to make it compatible for iphone 6 and 6+.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift Language you can use:

```
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height;
```

For Objective C you can use:

```
  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width : For Width
  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height : For Height
```

Comment: I want to code UI for one device only and both iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus should adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Ya dude. U can use this code only once then it'll adjust all screen size in all device

Comment: Dude this thing will give me screen height and width only. Suppose I need to define an image view. then i must give it different frames for iphone 6 and iphone 6p b'coz if we don't reframe it then there could be a lot of space left which would look ugly. Download a live app that you have developed. and shift your code to xcode 6 then match the difference. Live app would be auto adjusted by the ios but new apps need to be some changes.

Comment: ok,  i agree with u but this is my screen size. using this screen size u have to set your imageview or whatever u use